# How do I run test cases in postgresql?

Tags: .net, postgresql

I want to drop/create a database, run my test cases every time I run my app. From my understanding postgresql must know the database when it creates the connection. So when I write this

```
new NpgsqlConnection("host=localhost;username=foo;password='bar';");
```

postgresql will automatically use the database foo. Because I'm using foo I can't drop/create it. So my question is how do I drop/create a database each time I run my app and is it possible to have an in memory database?

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect several times for this. If you would use `psql`, you could script it with `\c` metacommand, eg:

```
t=# create database foo1;
CREATE DATABASE
t=# \c foo1;
You are now connected to database "foo1" as user "vao".
foo1=# begin;
BEGIN
foo1=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2017-04-03 21:00:34.296285+01
(1 row)

foo1=# end;
COMMIT
foo1=# \c t
You are now connected to database "t" as user "vao".
t=# drop database foo1;
DROP DATABASE
```

So you could save all above commands to sql file and run it with `psql`, but in you case, you have to make `new NpgsqlConnection`, create database, connect to it with new `new NpgsqlConnection`, run tests, connect back to foo and rop db from it...

Comment: I'll have to do it in .NET. I don't want to switch between the terminal and .NET every time I run something. I don't have psql installed on windows (there was an error last time I tried). I'm using putty to forward local connections to my debian VM which is running postgresql

Answer (score 0):

That's what the administrative database `postgres` is there for.

You must close all connections to database `foo`, establish a connection to `postgres` with a user that has the `CREATEDB` privilege and create the database.

To facilitate initialization of the new database, you can use a preconfigured *template database* that you can specify during `CREATE DATABASE`.

Comment: I don't see the connection.

Comment: Your suggestion still failed and IDK why. However I got around the problem. Instead of using an alternative schema/database, I used a different name than my username and I was able to drop/create fine

Comment: Then you probably tried to use a user that is no superuser or does not own the database. The error message would have told you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by having create database permission and using a database that isn't my name (for some reason I can't connect to a dummy database and drop the database if it's my name).